# Search and replace in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, replace

I have below multidimensional array and I want to replace value of

```
 $data['meta']['attr']['road'] with an array ['test']
```

Thing is I don't know keys they are only available through  keys array

```
$keys = ['meta', 'attr', 'road'];
```

This is just an example keys might be anything  hence want to search each element, check it and replace if key is found

My multidimensional array is below:

```
$data = ['meta' => [
             'time' => 11.364,
             'count' => 3,
              'attr' => [
                    'id'=> 7845,
                     'road' => [
                         'length' => 'km',
                         'width' => 'm'
                               ]
                        ]
                   ],
          'Assets' => [15,78,89]

        ];
```

Looks complicated search and replace algorithm really stuck ...any thoughts?

Comment: okay, I have modified question ...I want to search with $keys array ...that array is dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$keys = ['meta', 'attr', 'road'];

$arr = &$data;
foreach($keys as $key)
{
    $arr = &$arr[$key];
}

$arr = ['test'];
```

Comment: Thanks @Mex...works good...need to understand how it works with passing  by reference

Answer (score 0):

You can access multidimensional array values using brackets and *keys*.

```
// set
$someArray['key']['key'] = 'value';
// get
$someVar = $someArray['key']['key'];
```

[See arrays section on Php reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

So in your case it is;

```
$data['meta']['attr']['road'] = array('test' => 'value');
```